# VB .NET - Strange result during addition

Tags: vb.net

Today I am facing to the issue in addition Double + 1.

`Console.WriteLine(-1.09 + 1)` - Returns 0,0900000000000001

`Console.WriteLine(-1.05 + 1)` - Returns 0,05

I was testing the range of double when it give me strange values and I have found that wrong is onlz interval -1.06 to -1.09.

Work with Visual studio 16.4.5, framework target 4.7.2.

Tried the console.writeline and also other tests with values in variables.

Is that bug or I do something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: use decimal data type and you will be fine.. It is caused, that float data type have floating point.... CDec(-1.09) + CDec(1.0) = -0.09

Comment: Looks good, thanks sir!

Comment: Floating point is based on binary fractions rather than decimal fractions, and there are many numbers (1.09 among them) that cannot be exactly represented in floating point.  Thus, you can get small rounding errors as you observe here.  The runtime and debugger try to be smart about how they display things to avoid surprising results like this, but they don't always succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Ksenak Will use CDec() function with more significant digits.

Who need to learn more about that [can do it here](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html)